# Use map and switchMap together

Tags: javascript, rxjs, operators

I have an observable with object containing usual field and other observable. I want to get sequence containing this field and the value of corresponding observable firing together with inner observable.

For example:

```
var smth$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  take(3),
  map(i => ({
    id: String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + i),
    value$: interval(300).pipe(
      take(10),
      map(j => i*10 + j)
    )
  }))
)
```

I can easily get sequence of `id` field via `map`:

```
smth$.pipe(
  map(x => x.id)
)
```

[image: ids by <code>map</code>]

Also I can get sequence of `value`s via `switchMap`:

```
smth$.pipe(
  switchMap(x => x.value$)
)
```

[image: values by <code>switchMap</code>]

But how can I get a sequence of pairs with both `id` and `value`?

[image: desired sequence]

Runable example: https://rxviz.com/v/R85xKw6J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flat solution: https://rxviz.com/v/j8ArKWEo

```
smth$.pipe(
  switchMap(x => x.value$, (x, d) => x.id + d)
)
```

Comment: You missed an argument, but in general it works. I've fixed this mistake, hope you bhave no objections.

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
smth$.pipe(
    switchMap(x => x.value$.pipe(
        map(d => x.id + d)
    ))
)
```

Comment: Nice. I'll accept this answer if there is no flat solution.